# Inserting data by user id

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I'm new to using database/sql so any links and education reads would be nice.
Right now it's inserting into the use column, which I understand because there no in id to the query, how can I make it so?

```
public function update_balance($balance){

    $query  = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`balance`) VALUES (?)");

    $query->bindValue(1, $balance);

    try{
        $query->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }   
}
```

}

Here's me calling the function

```
$user       = $users->userdata($_SESSION['id']);
$balance    = $user['balance'];
```

> $users->update_balance($balance);

I'm connecting via pdo if that makes any differencehttp://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

The table

### ID     | Username  | Balance

1      | Something | 400

This site was really useful to figure it out
http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

```
$query  = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE users set balance = ? WHERE  id = ?");
$query->bindValue(1, $balance);
$query->bindValue(2, $id);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?  Add an ID?

Comment: Sorry, but I think the question is not clear. What exactly would you like to do?

Comment: How do i store it to the user thats logged in rather that making a new row

Comment: @user3026745 where is the logged in User's ID stored?

Comment: Show us your table schema.....**list of columns** in the table

Comment: The id is stored in a session and I tried to show my table!

Comment: did you just make an update to your question that answered your own question? is that what happened here?

Answer (score 0):

you add a WHERE clause to tell it which row to insert into or to update.

what you are saying above is always add a new record with just this balance in it.

maybe something like this:

```
"INSERT INTO `users` ('id',`balance`) VALUES (?,?)"
```

and

```
$query->bindValue($user, $balance);
```

Comment: Thats just going to make a new row with an id right? I already hvave the id, I just need to chance the balance to that id